# django rest framework lookup_field through OneToOneField

Tags: python, django, rest, django-rest-framework

https://gist.github.com/ranman/3d97ea9054c984bca75e

**Desired Behavior**
User lookup happens by the username: `/api/users/randall`
Speaker lookup happens by the username as well: `/api/speakers/randall`

**Constraints**
Not all users are speakers. All speakers are users.

**models.py**

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Speaker(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
```

**serializers.py**

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('url', 'username', 'email', 'groups')
        lookup_field = 'username'
 
class SpeakerSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    user = serializers.HyperlinkedRelatedField(
        view_name='user-detail',
        read_only=True,
        lookup_field='username'
    )
    class Meta:
        model = Speaker
        lookup_field = 'user'
```

**views.py**

```
class UserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
    lookup_field = 'username'
    
class SpeakerViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Speaker.objects.all().select_related('user')
    serializer_class = SpeakerSerializer
    lookup_field = "user"
```

I've tried various different invocations of lookup_field and serializer types to get this working to no avail. It may not be possible without a lot more code. I'm just wondering what direction I can take.

Comment: Have you tried using double underscores in the `lookup_field` to see if that can work? It'd be similar to a queryset filter.

Comment: I've tried using `lookup_field = "user__username"` and it doesn't work. I've tried using that on both the model and the view to no avail :(   


    `'Speaker' object has no attribute 'user__username'`

Comment: @ranman what do you want ? do you want  to serialize a related object ?

Comment: I want to be able to lookup the speaker object by the username on the user  associated with the speaker

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is how I managed to hack it

#### models.py

```
from django.db import models    
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Speaker(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)

    @property
    def user__username(self):
        return self.user.username
    
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

#### serializers.py

```
from .models import Speaker
from rest_framework import serializers
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class UserSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('url', 'username', 'email', 'groups')
        lookup_field = 'username'

class SpeakerSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    user = serializers.HyperlinkedRelatedField(
        view_name='user-detail',
        read_only=True,
        lookup_field='username'
    )
    class Meta:
        model = Speaker
        fields = ('url', 'user')
        lookup_field = 'user__username'
```

#### view.py

```
from .models import Speaker
from .serializers import SpeakerSerializer, UserSerializer

from rest_framework import viewsets
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class UserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
    lookup_field = 'username'

class SpeakerViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Speaker.objects.all().select_related('user')
    serializer_class = SpeakerSerializer
    lookup_field = 'user__username'
```

Comment: Actually it doesn't work -- for some reason this doesn't allow 2 things: the user field is no longer able to be written to when you create a new speaker, the speaker is no longer renderable on items that have relations to it

Comment: How can i reproduce your errors? I mean I tried to create a new `speaker` via the python shell and it pass with no problems, if you try to create a `speaker` via the `api`, well the `user` field is marked as `read-only`, that's why it doesn't work. I also created a dummy model having `OneToOneField` to the `speaker`, this also worked with both `ModelSerializer` and `HyperlinkedModelSerializer` with the 2nd one i just had to redefine the `speaker` field with as `HyperlinkedRelatedField` with `lookup_field='user__username'`(the same thing was done in the `SpeakerSerializer` for the `user` field.

Answer (score 1):

The only thing I changed from your code is to override the `get_object` method by filtering with the username instead of the default `pk`. I also changed the `lookup_field` to a descriptive name and used `ModelSerializer` and `StringRelated` in the `serializer.py`.

**models.py**

```
class Speaker(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

**serializer.py**

```
class SpeakerSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user = serializers.StringRelatedField(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Speaker
        lookup_field = "username"
        fields = "__all__"
```

**views.py**

```
class SpeakerViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Speaker.objects.all().select_related("user")
    serializer_class = SpeakerSerializer
    lookup_field = "username"

    def get_object(self):
        """Return the object for this view."""
        return get_object_or_404(self.queryset, user__username=self.kwargs["username"])
```

**urlconf**

```
 api/ ^speaker/$ [name='speaker-list']
 api/ ^speaker\.(?P<format>[a-z0-9]+)/?$ [name='speaker-list']
 api/ ^speaker/(?P<username>[^/.]+)/$ [name='speaker-detail']
 api/ ^speaker/(?P<username>[^/.]+)\.(?P<format>[a-z0-9]+)/?$ [name='speaker-detail']
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this approach?

```
class SpeakerViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Speaker.objects.all().select_related('user')
    serializer_class = SpeakerSerializer
    filter_backends = (filters.DjangoFilterBackend,)
    filter_fields = ('user', 'user__username',)
```

Comment: `'Speaker' object has no attribute 'user__username'` doesn't seem to work. I might have implemented it incorrectly.

Answer (score 0):

#### I'm fetching user's settings with user's ID  [GET / Update]

---

**urls.py**

```
path('user/<int:user_id>/settings/preferences/', UserPreferenceSettingsView.as_view(), name="settings_preferences")
```

**models.py**

```
class UserSetting(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    adult_lock = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    child_lock = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    promotional_email = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    update_email = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

**views.py**

```
class UserPreferenceSettingsView(generics.RetrieveUpdateAPIView):
    http_method_names = ['get', 'patch']    
    serializer_class = UserPreferenceSettingsSerializer

    def get_object(self):
        lookup_field = self.kwargs["user_id"]
        return get_object_or_404(UserSetting, user__pk=lookup_field)
```

If you need to fetch from `username` just replace `user_id to username` and url `<int:user_id>` to `<username> or <str:username>`

Comment: It might be useful to use `return get_object_or_404(UserSetting, user__pk=self.kwargs.get(self.lookup_field))`