# Django Rest Framework - Specify a custom lookup field for related ModelSerializer

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Sorry if this is a repeat, I tried searching for this with no luck.

I would like to know, how to specify a lookup field for a related model.

For example I have models related using a foreign key like so

```
class Quiz(models.Model):                                                                                      
    guid = models.CharField(max_length=11, unique=True, blank=True)

class Result(models.Model):
    guid = models.CharField(max_length=11, unique=True, blank=True)
    quiz = models.ForeignKey(Quiz)
```

Here I use `guid` as my unique identifier and I have my model serializers as below.

```
class QuizSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):                                                                                 
    results = ResultSerializer(many=True, required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = Quiz
        fields = ('guid', 'results')

class ResultSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    #lookup_field = 'guid' => Does not seem to work??

    class Meta:
        model = BroncoResult
        fields = ('guid',)
```

In the view I use `viewsets.ModelViewSet`

```
class QuizViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):                                                                                          
    queryset = Quiz.objects.all()
    serializer_class = QuizSerializer
    lookup_field = 'guid'
```

Which returns data like this

`{"guid": "12312312312", "results": [{"guid": "45645645666"}, {"guid": "78978978999"}]}`

I can specify the lookup field be `guid` for the `Quiz` model, in the `QuizViewSet` but how can I specify the lookup field be `guid` for the `Result` model in the serializer?

I seem to be getting the following error on a PUT request

`{"results": [{"guid": ["Result with this Guid already exists."]}`

which I think is because it is trying to retrieve the record by `id` and not finding it, and throwing the error because it tries to create a new record with the same unique guid.

Any body know how to specify that the result field use `guid` as the lookup as well?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Instead of `lookup_field = 'guid'`, try with `lookup_field = 'result__guid'`. Here is a [similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29068097/django-rest-framework-lookup-field-through-onetoonefield/29073607#29073607).