How to retireve details by related onetoonefield in Djang Rest Framework?
Hello consider the following simple scenario:
class User(models.Model):
     email = ...
     fname = ...
     lname = ...

class UserPreferences(models.Model):
     user = models.OneToOneField(User, to_field="email", ...)
     preferences = ...

Now the UserPreferences table in the db contains id, preferences, user_id.
I want to get the preferences of a user by email.
I want to use RetrieveAPIView.
How to do this?
What is the role of to_field if it stores the id of user anyway?
I tried the following:
class UserPreferencesRetrieveView(generics.RetrieveAPIView):
    serializer_class = UserPreferencesSerializer
    queryset = UserPreferences.objects.all()
    lookup_field = "email"

I got the error:
Cannot resolve keyword 'email' into field. Choices are: id, preferences, user, user_id


To answer your question you should use get_queryset method with your URL kwargs:
class UserPreferencesRetrieveView(generics.RetrieveAPIView):
    serializer_class = UserPreferencesSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        email = self.kwargs['email']
        return UserPreferences.objects.filter(user__email=email)

or
If you want go with lookup_field so you should do somthing like this lookup_field = 'user__email' in you view set:
class UserPreferencesRetrieveView(generics.RetrieveAPIView):
    serializer_class = UserPreferencesSerializer
    queryset = UserPreferences.objects.all()
    lookup_field = 'user__email'

and use of to_field

The field on the related object that the relation is to. By default, Django uses the primary key of the related object. If you reference a different field, that field must have unique=True. for more details docs


Thanks for the answer. I just checked the database and find that the email is actually stored but as "user_id" which I think is misleading it should be called "phone_number". So using user_id as a lookup was enough if the field is linked to email.

I have a minor question. I searched the entire documentation of Django Rest Framework without finding the "__"" notation you used. Where you find it?

The Answer is right but I can't accept nor upvote. I don't have enough reputations.

For '__' notation, you can refer this link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29073607
